# Not able to save state of TabBar tab position in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to use **TabBar** and **Bottom Navigation bar** together. I am able to save state of **tabview** when I switch to different page using bottom navigation bar. When I switch back, the position of the selected tab and pageview do not match.

What could be possibly wrong? Please help me with example code of using tab bar and bottom navigation bar together.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class TabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TabbedPage({Key key, this.pageIndex, this.tabCount}) : super(key: key);
  final int pageIndex;
  final int tabCount;

  _TabbedPageState createState() => new _TabbedPageState();
}

class _TabbedPageState extends State<TabbedPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  int _getInitialIndex() {
    int initialIndex = PageStorage.of(context).readState(
          context,
          identifier: widget.pageIndex,
        ) ??
        0;
    print("Initial Index ${initialIndex}");
    return initialIndex;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(
      length: widget.tabCount,
      vsync: this,
      initialIndex: _getInitialIndex(),
    );
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      print("New Index ${_tabController.index}");
      PageStorage.of(context).writeState(
        context,
        _tabController.index,
        identifier: widget.pageIndex,
      );
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: new TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: new List<Tab>.generate(widget.tabCount, (int tabIndex) {
              var name = 'Tab ${widget.pageIndex}-${tabIndex}';
              return new Tab(text: name);
            }),
          ),
        ),
        new Expanded(
          child: new TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children:
                new List<Widget>.generate(widget.tabCount, (int tabIndex) {
              return new ListView.builder(
                  key: new PageStorageKey<String>(
                      'TabBarView:${widget.pageIndex}:$tabIndex'),
                  itemCount: 20,
                  itemExtent: 60.0,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Text(
                      'View ${widget.pageIndex}-${tabIndex}-${index}'));
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

const List<int> tabCounts = const <int>[5, 8];

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  PageController _controller = new PageController();
  int currentIndex = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new PageView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: new List<Widget>.generate(tabCounts.length, (int index) {
          return new TabbedPage(
            pageIndex: index,
            tabCount: tabCounts[index],
          );
        }),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
            _controller.jumpToPage(index);
          });
        },
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text("Settings"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

reference : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20341

Answer (score 1):

Set initialIndex, Take a variable which update your initial and last selected tab position, This variable must be update with the new value when you change any tab.

```
int lastTabPosition=0;

DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      initialIndex: lastTabPosition,
      child:  Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  Text("Tabs"),
          bottom:  TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
               Tab(text: 'One'),
               Tab(text: 'Two'),
               Tab(text: 'Three'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body:  TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```